# Freeswitch (Callcenter): moh-sound doesn't play

Tags: centos6, freeswitch

I have freeswitch 1.2.53 installed on Centos 6 server (OpenVZ CT). There is one test "call center":

Someone is calling, then user hears IVR menu (works well) and when button "1" is pressed the call is sended to **support** group:
`<entry action="menu-exec-app" digits="1" param="bridge group/support@${domain_name}"/>`

This is queue configuration:

```
    <queue name="support@default">
      <param name="strategy" value="longest-idle-agent"/>
      <param name="moh-sound" value="/usr/local/freeswitch/sounds/fur_elise.wav"/>
      <!--<param name="record-template" value="$${base_dir}/recordings/${strftime(%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)}.${destination_number}.${caller_id_number}.${uuid}.wav"/>-->
      <param name="time-base-score" value="system"/>
      <param name="max-wait-time" value="0"/>
      <param name="max-wait-time-with-no-agent" value="0"/>
      <param name="max-wait-time-with-no-agent-time-reached" value="5"/>
      <param name="tier-rules-apply" value="false"/>
      <param name="tier-rule-wait-second" value="300"/>
      <param name="tier-rule-wait-multiply-level" value="true"/>
      <param name="tier-rule-no-agent-no-wait" value="false"/>
      <param name="discard-abandoned-after" value="60"/>
      <param name="abandoned-resume-allowed" value="false"/>
    </queue>
```

The problem is here:
`<param name="moh-sound" value="/usr/local/freeswitch/sounds/fur_elise.wav"/>`

It doesn't play on user's phone when queue phones are ringing and user is waiting for answer.

File exists and there are no errors in log while waiting for someone to pick up phone. Just silence.

Tried to replace value to relative path (`/sounds/fur_elise.wav`), also there was attempt to use default value `$${hold_music}` and enter it in `vars.xml` - nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

My bad - using wrong concept. Moh is used when operator is holding call. To play background music the right way is to configure `ringback` directive in diaplan:
`<action application="set" data="ringback=/path/to/file"/>`